Why is Type 'string' not assignable to a Union type of strings in TypeScript?
I have a union type:
type FormFieldName =
    | "product details"
    | "objectives"
    | "stakeholders"
    | "functional requirements"
    | "non-functional requirements"
    | "assumptions and constraints"
    | "dependencies"
    | "acceptance criteria"
    | "risk analysis"
    | "priority effort"
    | "version history";

and I'm trying to set the correct type of the accumulator object (fieldsObject) here:

const internalFormFields = prdDetails.formFields.reduce(
    (fieldsObject, field) => {
        const name: FormFieldName = field.name as FormFieldName;
        fieldsObject[name] = field.name;
        return fieldsObject;
    },
    {} as {
        [key in FormFieldName]: FormFieldName;
    }
);

For this part:

fieldsObject[name] = field.name;


TypeScript is complaining Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'FormFieldName'.
prdDetails has the type PrdDataObject:
type PrdFormFieldsParamDefault = string | number | boolean | unknown[] | null;
type PrdFormFields<T> = {
    name: string;
    details: { [key: string]: T | PrdFormFields<T> | PrdFormFields<T>[] };
};

type PrdDataObject<
    T =
        | PrdFormFieldsParamDefault
        | Record<string, PrdFormFieldsParamDefault>
        | Record<string, PrdFormFieldsParamDefault>[],
> = {
    type: string | null;
    title: string | null;
    chosenLanguage: string | null;
    formFields: PrdFormFields<T>[] | null;
};


Here is a minimal reproducible example for this problem
on GitHub.
I've tried using type assertions in many manner of ways but it isn't helping out, and also type guards isn't something I think is correct to use.
I have no idea why a Type string can't be assigned to a Union type of strings.
I'm aware of Typescript - Type 'string' is not assignable to union type of strings. However, it doesn't align with my problem and give me the solution I need.

It’s not a union of arbitrary strings; it’s a union of specific strings, and there is no way to statically ensure that field.name is one of those strings.

keeping it without type assertions - const internalFormFields = prdDetails.formFields.reduce( (fieldsObject, field) => { const name = field.name; fieldsObject[name] = field.name; return fieldsObject; }, {} ); typescript complains Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.. So, how do I set the type for the structure of the fieldsObject?

You literally have the answer one line above the error: field.name as FormFieldName;

even with that type assertion, typescript still complains at fieldsObject[name] - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'FormFieldName' can't be used to index type '{}'.   Property 'product details' does not exist on type '{}'.

Then you need to post a [mre].

Because not all strings are those strings, in short.

Here is a minimal reproducible example: example

With that minimal example the code doesn't produce any error if you paste it into https://www.typescriptlang.org/ for example (if you just add field.name as FormFieldName;).

a red error line is drawn under fieldsObject[name] in my editor and still giving the Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'FormFieldName' complain. Here: if (prdDetails.formFields) {  const internalFormFields = prdDetails.formFields.reduce(   (fieldsObject, field) => {    const name = field.name as FormFieldName; fieldsObject[name] = field.name; return fieldsObject; }, {} as { [key in FormFieldName]: FormFieldName } ); }.

fieldsObject[name] = field.name as FormFieldName;

• A github file does not count as a [mre]; it needs to be here, as plaintext. • Assuming your text code here is the same, then previous commenters are correct: an arbitrary string is not likely to be one of the particular strings in your union, so TS complains. If you want to assert, you can, as you sort of almost did except you didn't follow through. But are you sure that assertion is correct? How do you know the string will be one of the ones in that union? Where is the [mre] that shows this? The github code has null there. Please [edit] with a true [mre].


I have no idea why a Type string can't be assigned to a Union type of strings.

Here is a simple counterexample: "hello" is a valid value of type string. But "hello" is not a member of the type FormFieldName.
Which means we have found an example of a value that is of type string but not of type FormFieldName. Ergo, string cannot be assignable to FormFieldName.

Then, how can I tell TypeScript the structure of the fieldObject accumulator in the formFields.reduce(...), since trying type assertion isn't working?

fieldsObject has keys with the type FormFieldName, while field.name has the type string, and any string can't be assigned to FormFieldName since FormFieldName is a subset of all possible string values.
To make this work you should change the type of field.name.
One alternative is to change the type PrdFormFields so it's name always is a FormFieldName.
type PrdFormFields<T> = {
    name: FormFieldName;
    details: { [key: string]: T | PrdFormFields<T> | PrdFormFields<T>[] };
};

If that isn't feasible you could change name to be generic, and make sure that FormFields has the type PrdFormFields<T, FormFieldName>
type PrdFormFields<T, N = string> = {
    name: N;
    details: { [key: string]: T | PrdFormFields<T> | PrdFormFields<T>[] };
};


Can you check this reproducible example to see if you can edit your answer to better fit the solution I need, please?
